# Increment column id based on another id

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table :

- `project_user_id` refers to user's login id.
- `name` refers to project name.
- `id` is an incremented column based on a new name entry and refers to the project id.

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJGl2.png). How to make `id` column increment from 1 based on a different `project_user_id` and therefore name input? [Desired table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOI0y.png).

I am using SQLite and `db.execute` in my Python Flask application.

Comment: [I don't think your requirement gives out of the box](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q1). Do it by yourself by calculating the `id` e.g. via `SELECT count(*) FROM tablename where project_user_id = ?`.

Comment: apologies, id refers to the project id in my table. When running your sql statement I return a value. I am trying to make id autoincrement again from 1 based on a new project_user_id. Is this possible with autoincrement ?

Comment: No, an AUTOINCREMENT based on a special table column is not preconceived because it is too specific.

Comment: That makes sense. How could I go about trying to solve my problem?

Comment: You already have a suitable answer and explanation, trying to maintain a partitioned ID sequence really is fools gold, calculate the sequence as needed, do not store it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave id alone, id should be a unique identifier for your row that has no meaning whatsoever, other than used to uniquely identify your row.   if you want to display something else use a view.    something like

```
 create or replace view myview as 
 select project_user_id, name,
 row_number() over (partition by project_user_id order by null) as id
 from mytable
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How could I set the row_number() function up as a trigger for a new project_user_id ?

Comment: nope, use a view.  keeping that trigger in sync going to be a maintenance nightmare, just use a view